# Python does not want to work with the last column

Tags: python-3.x

I am working with a .txt file. I want to work with the columns. The first 3 columns are giving back the right information but the last one constantly coming back as empty.

Content of the .txt file (it does not have a header)

```
25  26  41  44
04  29  33  37
06  23  39  43
08  12  23  40
12  24  32  37
03  27  30  43
20  21  26  32
```

Script:

```
file = open(csvfile, 'r')
data = file.readlines()
countstr = []
    for d in data:
        countstr.append(d.split('\t')[0])
        countstr.append(d.split('\t')[1]) 
        countstr.append(d.split('\t')[2]) 
        countstr.append(d.split('\t')[-1])
```

If I write out the the content with `print(d.split('\t')[2])` it will print:

```
41
33
39
23
32
30
26
```

If I print the last column out `print(d.split('\t')[-1])` it will print:

```
44

37

43

40

37

43

32
```

It looks like there is one extra line between the column elements but it is not in the file.

I did reformat the .txt file.
I did try it as a .csv file.
I did try it with different dividers.
I changed the last column data.

I could not find anything on the internet regarding this, and nothing did help so far.

When I added an extra column to the file, it could read the column what I needed but when I deleted it, it could not read it again.

Please, is there any ideal?

Comment: That is the newline character `\n`.

Comment: I did try replacing the split character from \t to \n but did not help. ( countstr.append(d.split('\n')[-1]) ) 
I thought there is something in the last column what I cannot see so I did copy the first column to the last column by overwriting it but did not help.

Comment: I did create a brand new file with the content "01 02 03 04 05 06 07" the result is the same. It has to be the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as said in the comments it's because at the end o of every line you have a newline character (`\n`), to remove it from your output you have to use `str.strip('\n')`,

the below code should work

```
file = open(csvfile, 'r')
data = file.readlines()
countstr = []
    for d in data:
        countstr.append(d.split('\t')[0].strip('\n'))
        countstr.append(d.split('\t')[1].strip('\n')) 
        countstr.append(d.split('\t')[2].strip('\n')) 
        countstr.append(d.split('\t')[-1].strip('\n'))
```

Comment: Wow I never see to use the .strip('\n')) like this! Thank you so so much I spent 2 days with this issue!